# Polite way to say "white-washed"?

Tags: word-choice

What is a polite way to describe a person as "white-washed", i.e. a person of visible color who acts and talks and cultured the way a white Western person is. Or is white-washed OK ?

Comment: Seems to have the potential to be offensive no matter how you word it. Sometimes, what's impolite is not the wording, but the concept. What is the context in which you've be using this term? Are you addressing the person, or giving a description of somebody you don't know personally, like a historical figure? Please give more context or your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: FWIW, in the US "white washed", when not referring to Tom Sawyer's fence, is usually used to mean that some sordid affair of some relatively prominent person is made to appear "clean" via various PR gimmicks.  I've never heard it applied to a black person attempting to be "white".

Comment: It’s not meant as an answer to your question, but it’s not impossible that somebody’s been “**brainwashed**” somewhere along the way into thinking that how “cultured” one appears to be in speech and action is related somehow to 1) one’s skin color, and  2) how “cultured” one really is.

Comment: I don't think there is a polite way to imply that someone should or should not behave a certain way because of their race. Are you looking for something polite like good manners, or something that isn't vulgar as in shouldn't say it in front of children? Can you give an example sentence where you would like to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **westernized**

> "Westernize" definion: to cause (someone or something) to make familiar or have the qualities (or imperfections), practices or characteristics that are associated with Western Europe
> and North America.
>
> Example: *Mustafa Kemal Atatürk (1881-1938) was an army officer who founded an independent Republic of Turkey out of the ruins of the Ottoman Empire. He then served as Turkey’s first president from 1923 until his death in 1938, implementing reforms that rapidly secularized and westernized the country*.

Answer (score -1):

An **Uncle Tom** is a black person who is subservient and deferential to whites, as was the character in the story ("Uncle Tom's Cabin") from which the term originates.

A better choice for a black person who "tries to act white," whatever that perception means, is **Oreo cookie**.  This means (s)he is **"black on the outside, white on the inside."**

By the way, **white-washed** is less common in this sense in the U.S.

Comment: Are any of these polite? They all seem rude to me. I would not call anyone an "Uncle Tom" or "Oreo cookie," and if I did, I wouldn't expect the person to take it well.

Comment: No, you're not likely to find a polite way to put across this concept, especially if you say it to someone's face, because it means that you're dictating how you feel certain people should act and live their lives.  They might not agree with you, and people who look like them might have something to say as well.  I'm just giving you the term that's most commonly used in the wild.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom - You apparently have no concept of how racially-charged "Uncle Tom" is.  "Oreo cookie" at least has a tinge of humor to it (and, one might argue, has better taste).